# includes <cstring> or <string> rises compile errors

Tags: visual-c++

Have simple console application that builds fine:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    return 0;
}
```

It alsow builds fine if I add line `#include <cstring>` (or (and) `#include <string>`)

```
#include <cstring>
#include "stdafx.h"

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    return 0;
}
```

If I add file `gc.c` just with only one include line ,`#include <cstring>` (or (and) `#include <string>`), compiler generates a lot of errors:

```
Error   2   error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'using'  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cstring  18  1   cstringerr
Error   43  error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'strxfrm'    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cstring  26  1   cstringerr
Error   41  error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'strtok' C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cstring  26  1   cstringerr
Error   39  error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'strstr' C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cstring  25  1   cstringerr
Error   37  error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'strspn' C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cstring  25  1   cstringerr
Error   35  error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'strrchr'    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cstring  25  1   cstringerr
Error   33  error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'strpbrk'    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cstring  24  1   cstringerr
Error   31  error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'strncpy'    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cstring  24  1   cstringerr
Error   29  error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'strncmp'    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cstring  24  1   cstringerr
Error   27  error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'strncat'    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cstring  23  1   cstringerr
Error   25  error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'strlen' C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cstring  23  1   cstringerr
Error   23  error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'strerror'   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cstring  23  1   cstringerr
Error   21  error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'strcspn'    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cstring  22  1   cstringerr
Error   19  error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'strcpy' C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cstring  22  1   cstringerr
Error   17  error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'strcoll'    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cstring  22  1   cstringerr
Error   15  error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'strcmp' C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cstring  21  1   cstringerr
Error   13  error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'strchr' C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cstring  21  1   cstringerr
Error   11  error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'strcat' C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cstring  21  1   cstringerr
Error   9   error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'memset' C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cstring  20  1   cstringerr
Error   7   error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'memmove'    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cstring  20  1   cstringerr
Error   5   error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'memcpy' C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cstring  20  1   cstringerr
Error   3   error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'memcmp' C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cstring  18  1   cstringerr
Error   4   error C2059: syntax error : ';' C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cstring  18  1   cstringerr
Error   6   error C2059: syntax error : ';' C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cstring  20  1   cstringerr
Error   8   error C2059: syntax error : ';' C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cstring  20  1   cstringerr
Error   10  error C2059: syntax error : ';' C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cstring  20  1   cstringerr
Error   12  error C2059: syntax error : ';' C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cstring  21  1   cstringerr
Error   14  error C2059: syntax error : ';' C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cstring  21  1   cstringerr
Error   16  error C2059: syntax error : ';' C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cstring  21  1   cstringerr
Error   18  error C2059: syntax error : ';' C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cstring  22  1   cstringerr
Error   20  error C2059: syntax error : ';' C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cstring  22  1   cstringerr
Error   22  error C2059: syntax error : ';' C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cstring  22  1   cstringerr
Error   24  error C2059: syntax error : ';' C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cstring  23  1   cstringerr
Error   26  error C2059: syntax error : ';' C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cstring  23  1   cstringerr
Error   28  error C2059: syntax error : ';' C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cstring  23  1   cstringerr
Error   30  error C2059: syntax error : ';' C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cstring  24  1   cstringerr
Error   32  error C2059: syntax error : ';' C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cstring  24  1   cstringerr
Error   34  error C2059: syntax error : ';' C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cstring  24  1   cstringerr
Error   36  error C2059: syntax error : ';' C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cstring  25  1   cstringerr
Error   38  error C2059: syntax error : ';' C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cstring  25  1   cstringerr
Error   40  error C2059: syntax error : ';' C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cstring  25  1   cstringerr
Error   42  error C2059: syntax error : ';' C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cstring  26  1   cstringerr
Error   44  error C2059: syntax error : ';' C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cstring  26  1   cstringerr
Error   1   error C2054: expected '(' to follow 'using' C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cstring  18  1   cstringerr
```

Looks like compiler does't understands anything that exists in include.

What is wrong with including `<cstring>` or `<string>` in additional cpp file?

Comment: BTW (not related to your compiler error), if you are using stdafx.h for precompiled headers, then stdafx.h must be the first file to include.

Comment: Yes, I have turned off precompiled headers

Answer (score 0):

Go to Property

> Properties > C/C++ > Advanced > Compile As and check Compile as C++
>   Code(/TP)

And allways make habit to include the file like this

```
#include "stdafx.h"    //Always include it first then other files.
#include <cstring>
```

Comment: 'Compile as C++ Code(/TP)' helped, but I suppose this is not a solution, because in some projects I will have both C and C++ libs. Why compiler acts in such a strange way?. I have turned off precompiled headers

Comment: @user1501700: I don't understand that. You are compiling gc.cpp, which is a cpp file (C++) and you are using the C++ include file cstring but you are complaining that this code does not compile as C?

Comment: My fall. I have gc.c, but not gc.cpp file. I have updated it in problem description